# Why we need to consider a probability ensemble and not just a probability distribution in the definition of Security under Simulation?

Tags: provable-security, security-definition, semantic-security, probability, simulation

I'm currently reading this classic paper ["How To Simulate It"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046.pdf) and on most of the definitions it is using the term probability ensemble to represent the message space. From my understanding a probability ensemble is like a stochastic process and a probability distribution is an instance of a stochastic process. For example, if we have $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ then we can consider it equivalent to $X(n)$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $X(5)$ for example is an instance of the probability ensemble, a probability distribution.

I'm kind of confused about why we need to consider this structure for the plaintext space. Actually, it would make more sense to me since we consider a non-uniform $PPT$ to consider this structure as the ciphertext space, but probably this isn't the case. Can you help me clarify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your plaintext space/ciphertext space distinction here. Could you try to clarify that part of your question?

As for $\{X_n\}_n$ vs $X(n)$, I would just say one reason to not consider probability ensambles as stochastic processes is that there is no reason to expect $X(n)$ and $X(n-1)$ to be connected in some way (say be martingale, or have any other property a stochastic process might typically have).
The main property you want from whatever way you formalize things as is a mapping from integers to probability distributions, so you can coherently use the notion of "negligible" functions (where $f(n)\in\mathsf{negl}(n)$ if $f(n) = n^{-\omega(1)}$), which are very useful for analysis.
This is really only relevant for asymptotic security though, for concrete security you'll typically set $n = 128$, and not work with arbitrary neglible functions (such as $f_0(n) = 2^{-(\log n)^2}$), and instead work with explicit inverse exponential functions ($f_1(n) = 2^{-n}$).

Comment: A question, what is $n^{-\omega(1)}$? I am familiar with $\Omega(1)$ denoting a quantity that grows at least like a constant with increasing $n.$ Just confused about the lowercase omega. Also I don't understand your distinction between the two functions given as arbitrary vs explicit. Did you mean to have a negative in the first exponent? Even assuming that my confusion remains since both have $n$ explicitly in the expression.

Comment: @kodlu $\omega(1)$ is a super-constant quantity, i.e. $>$ rather than $\geq$, similarly to how $O(1)$ and $o(1)$ are $\leq$ constant and $<$ constant. Formally $n^{-\omega(1)}$ are the functions that are of the form $(1/\mathsf{poly}(n))^{c(n)}$ for some super-constant $c(n)$, i.e. negligible functions.

Comment: @kodlu for $f_0$ and $f_1$, the point is that both are perfectly good negligible functions. But a security bound of the form $f_0$ is incredibly weak. An adversary that runs in $1/f_0(n)$ running time is not technically "efficient" (as this quantity is super-poly), but for an instance size $n = 2^{10}$ one has that $1/f_0(n) = 2^{100}$ running time, i.e. even for a relatively large instance size of $n\approx 1000$ it does not require $2^{128}$ running time.

Comment: very clear thank you

Answer (score 0):

**It was explained by Rafael Pass and Abhi Shelat in "A Cource in Cryptography", [[PS2010](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4830/2010fa/lecnotes.pdf)'Section 3.1: Computational Indistinguishability]**

---

### [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of an ensemble in this context is incorrect. An ensemble in this context is a sequence of probability distributions.

Given two probability distributions $X, Y$, you can consider the best-possible distinguishing probability (for distinguishers running in some bounded time) between a random sample from $X$ and a random sample from $Y$. You will get a number, and that is fine for concrete security. But if you want to consider asymptotic security, then you need to consider two infinite sequences of probability distributions $\{X_i\}_{i =1, \ldots}, \{Y_i\}_{i =1, \ldots}$ where the distributions are indexed by the security parameter.

I suggest looking at Katz-Lindell, "Introduction to Modern Cryptography (3rd edition)." They discuss this issue in Section 3.1 and more formally in Chapter 8 (especially Section 8.8).